# Can't write to .bash_profile file even when I am admin

Tags: mysql, bash, macos, terminal

I am trying to fix the problem with MySQL Server. When I type in terminal MySQL I get command not found.

I know I have to edit .bash_profile file and add to it this line:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

The problem is I can't write to it. I tried these commands:

```
brackets ~/.bask_profile
sudo brackets ~/.bash_profile
touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile
sudo touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile
```

All the time I get a message that I am not allowed to write to this file because it is protected.

My question is, how can I write to this file and start MySQL Server?

Thank you for your help.

Cheers

---

EDIT:

Output in terminal of command:

```
ls -l ~/.bash_profile
```

is

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff  447 13 paź 17:33 /Users/macos/.bash_profile
```

---

EDIT2:

1. Could you write to me about how to find the path to the .bash_profile file? I think changing the privileges of this file will be the solution to the problem.

Comment: Can you please run ``ls -l ~/.bash_profile`` and paste the output in your question?

Comment: this is probably a macos-specific problem. grant full disk access to your terminal program with system preferences: security & privacy: privacy: full disk access

Comment: try 'sudo vi ~/.bash_profile'. Side question, why is '~/.bash_profile' owned by root ? Usually, it is owned by the current user.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was using vi/vim editor:

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

Then in vi/vim I pasted this line:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

And saved it with this commands:

```
:wq!
```